# BMO in each dimension uniformly implies BMO in higher-dimensional space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to prove the following but don't know how. It is probably easy to generalize it to $\mathbb{R}^n$ if the case $n=2$ is proved.

Suppose $f(x, y)$, $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is for each $y$ a BMO($\mathbb{R}$) function in $x$, uniformly in $y$. Assume also that this holds when the roles of $x$ and $y$ are interchanged. Then $f \in BMO(\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: BMO? Do you mind defining that?

Comment: Its definition can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_mean_oscillation#Definition).

Comment: Just in case you missed that. It should be true as is stated in Stein's book (IV, §6.A, page 177), unfortunately with no external reference. I saw nothing like that in the book by Grafakos